# Adding Excel File and .TXT file into same Field in XPages

Tags: xpages

I woulld like to create then add 2 files into same file as attachment.
How can i do that? Please find below what i tried so far.
Excel files comes from resource/files and TXT file is just created during document saving progress.

```
importPackage(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel); 
var resourcePath = "/SampleExcelFile.xlsx";
var bantfile = java.lang.System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

var srtEk = "FileName1";      
var excelName = srtEk + ".xlsx";
var textFileName = srtEk + +".txt";

var excelFilePath = bantfile+"\\"+ excelName;
var ledesFilePath = bantfile+"\\"+ textFileName;

var inp = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
var wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
var sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
var row = sheet.getRow(2);
if (row == null) 
{
    row = sheet.createRow(2);
}
var cell = row.getCell(0);
if (cell == null) 
{
    cell = row.createCell(0);
}

cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.setCellValue(tempFilePath);

var fileOut = new java.io.FileOutputStream(excelFilePath);
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();

var fileOut = new java.io.FileOutputStream(ledesFilePath);
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();

var doc = database.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "frmTest");
var rtitem = doc.createRichTextItem("Body");
rtitem.embedObject(lotus.domino.local.EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, null, excelFilePath , null);
doc.save(true, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add as much attachments to a RichText field as you like.
Just add another embedObject line to your code:

```
rtitem.embedObject(lotus.domino.local.EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, null, ledesFilePath, null);
```